# Have CodeIgniter ignore a file

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

Is there a way to have codeIgniter ignore a HTML file in the CI root directory.  I am working on some jQuery ajax and the html file has to be in the same directory.

Comment: I bet this is an .htaccess problem, not a CodeIgniter problem. Could you please post your .htaccess rewrite section, and also mention what directory you're putting the html file in, relative to the application root?

Answer (score 1):

Why not have the .html file be included by a view? Would work the same, and you would not be breaking the **MVC** model.

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify "ignore"? If you have a root set up like:

```
/system
.htaccess
index.php
somefile.html
```

CI will ignore the somefile.html. If someone directly requests site.com/somefile.html, the server will serve the file. However, if you prevent that, jQuery cannot access it either.